# NameError при попытке создать StringScanner (Ruby)

Tags: строки, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Пишу консоль с полезными утилитами на языке Ruby и мне нужен простой лексер строки как в Java. Я нашел инструмент под названием StringScanner. Я создаю переменную с StringScanner:
`scanner = StringScanner.new(gets)`
И когда мне нужно вызвать функцию переменной, я получаю ошибку
`` undefined local variable or method `scanner' for main:Object (NameError) ``
Но если ввести вместо gets какую нибудь строку, то никаких ошибок не будет. С чем это связано?

Comment: А где и как вы код запускаете? У меня в консоли не воспроизводится ошибка, `scanner = StringScanner.new(gets)` ждет ввода и инициализируется с ним без ошибок

Comment: Упс, я забыл написать что дело в вызове функции. Перечитайте, пожалуйста

Comment: Хорошо, а где и как вы её создаёте и откуда к ней обращаетесь? Выглядит так, как будто в том месте, где вы вызываете `scanner`, никто о нём ничего не знает.  Кажется, нам нужно больше подробностей и кода

Comment: Я ее создаю в ```loop do``` и там же к ней обращаюсь

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста весь код к вопросу, чтобы можно было попробовать воспроизвести ошибку

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O3h2hSErZMlyAawTFwEp_0CPK3udBNfV/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Оформите пожалуйста вопрос так, чтобы в нём самом содержался весь необходимый код, и не было необходимости читать код и ходить по сторонним ссылкам